# Error when picking out unique numbers in an array

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

This is a problem in my textbook for my Java class where the user enters 10 integers. The program is supposed to read all integers and only display the unique numbers (not duplicated) as the output. I am having trouble understanding why my output is not picking up the last unique value in the array (5). Can anyone give some insight to this issue? Any help would be appreciated. (Since we are in the early stages of the class and understanding the language, our assignment is to complete this using a nested loop.)

-The output is:
 Enter 10 numbers: 1 2 3 2 1 6 3 4 5 2
 The number of distinct numbers is 5
 The distinct numbers are: 1 2 3 6 4

-When it should be:
 Enter 10 numbers: 1 2 3 2 1 6 3 4 5 2
 The number of distinct numbers is 6
 The distinct numbers are: 1 2 3 6 4 5

````
public class ch7e5{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.print("Enter 10 numbers: ");

        int[] numberArray = new int[10];
        //create array for all numbers

        int[] distinctArray = new int[10];
        //create array for distinct numbers

        int distinct = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)


            numberArray[i] = input.nextInt();

        distinctArray[0] = numberArray[0];
        //first value will be distinct

        for (int i = 1; i < numberArray.length; i++) {
        //loop to go through remaining values in numberArray

            boolean exists = false;
            //create boolean

            for (int j = 0; j < numberArray.length; j++) {
            //loop to check if value exists already in distinctArray

                if (numberArray[i] == distinctArray[j]) {

                    exists = true;


                    break;
                    //break out of inner loop

                }
            }

            if (exists == false) {
            //if value is unique then add it to the distinct array


                distinct++;
                distinctArray[distinct] = distinctArray[i];



            }
        }
        //}

        System.out.println("The number of distinct numbers is " + distinct);

        System.out.print("The distinct numbers are: ");

        for (int k = 0; k < distinct; k++)

            System.out.print(distinctArray[k] + " ");

    }

}```
````

Comment: `distinct++; distinctArray[distinct] = distinctArray[i] ` try to swap, add first, after increase counter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was here

```
distinct++;
distinctArray[distinct] = distinctArray[i];
```

1, you should increment `distinct` after adding a number to `distinctArray`, and 2, you should have done `distinctArray[distinct] = numberArray[i]`. Right now, you're just putting what is possibly a `0` into `distinctArray[distinct]`.

A shorter way to do it would be this

```
int[] distinctArray = Arrays.stream(numberArray).distinct().toArray();
System.out.println("The number of distinct numbers is " + distinctArray.length);
System.out.print("The distinct numbers are: ");
for (int d : distinctArray) System.out.print(d + " ");
```

Output:

```
Enter 10 numbers: 1 2 3 2 1 6 3 4 5 2
The number of distinct numbers is 6
The distinct numbers are: 1 2 3 6 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 distinct numbers, 1, 2, and 3 are not any of them as they appear twice. The output should be 6 4 5. I'm not sure how you got 5 distinct numbers here, maybe you inputted them wrong? I would try not using a scanner at first and try putting the numbers in the array manually. Additionally, I would create a boolean array length 10 starting all true to record if numbers are distinct. If a number appears twice, the corresponding boolean in the array will be false. I will update this with code once i have written it.

EDIT: apparently having a duplicate does not delete it from the distinct list. If this is the case, please elaborate on the title.

Here is my code:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int inputs = 3;
    int[] numberArray = new int[inputs];
    int distinct = 0;
    boolean[] mirror = new boolean[inputs];

    //just setting up arrays
    for(int i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++) {
      //numberArray[i] = i;
      mirror[i] = true;
    }
    numberArray[0] = 1;

    //finds out what numbers are not distinct
    for (int x = 0; x < numberArray.length; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < numberArray.length; y++) {
        System.out.println("x is " + x);
        System.out.println("y is " + y);
        if(numberArray[x] == numberArray[y] && x != y) {
          System.out.println(numberArray[x] + " is not distinct");
          mirror[x] = false;//if current position in array matches any other position, number is not distinct
        }
      }
    }

    //calculates how many are distinct
    for(int j = 0; j < inputs; j++) {
      if(mirror[j]) {distinct++;}
    }

    //outputs text
    System.out.println("The number of distinct numbers is " + distinct);
    System.out.print("The distinct numbers are: ");
    for(int k = 0; k < inputs; k++){
      if(mirror[k]) {System.out.print(numberArray[k] + " ");}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 1, 1 -  twice but distinct

Comment: @TraianGEICU because 1 appears twice it is not distinct, though?

Comment: `When it should be: Enter 10 numbers: 1 2 3 2 1 6 3 4 5 2 The number of distinct numbers is 6 The distinct numbers are: 1 2 3 6 4 5`. Fine now the result !

Comment: @TraianGEICU but you said "read all integers and only display the unique numbers (not duplicated) as the output."

Comment: 1, 1 - twice but distinct, this i said

Comment: think he put it wrong !  need to count Distinct not unique

Comment: @TraianGEICU I misunderstood, a duplicate will not remove it entirely from the list. I will try to help with that then.